# php classes use of $game->details->something

Tags: php, class

I dont understand what people do when they are using $game->details->something in php code. Can some one please explain what it is.

Comment: It's Object Oriented Programming. Have a look at this link : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code means that `$game` is a instance of probably a Game class, in which details is another object(just another attribute) within the Game class, and something is an attribute within the Details class.

**Semi-Pseudo-Code**

```
class Game {

  public $details;

  function __construct(){
    $this->details = new Details();
  }
}

class Details {
  public $something;

  public __construct(){
    $this->something = "Mike";
  }
}

  $game = new Game();
  echo $game->details->something; // prints Mike
```

Answer (score 0):

They're accessing instance variables.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $bar = 'Qux';
}
$foo = new Foo;
echo $foo->bar;
```

Comment: Sorry, but if you downvote a comment, would you at least have the decency to say why my answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

When you type for example `$game->start();` you call the method `start` from the object stored in `$game`. It's is only possible when the object game has a method called `start`.

Try reading someting about Object Oriented Programming (OOP).